# Create a search box that returns JSON results on same page

Tags: php, json, search, filter, html-table

I have a JSON file that I have parsed using PHP. I take the JSON data and output it into a table. Below is a screenshot of what the output looks like:

[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is for a user to enter the room number, press "SEARCH" and then have the data in the table auto scroll to whatever room number the user entered.

Here is what the JSON data looks like:

```
 "apiVersion" : "0.1",
   "data" : {
      "roomCount" : 105,
      "rooms" : [
         {
            "room_number" : "104",
            "services" : [
               {
                  "adult" : {
                     "enabled" : false
                  },
                  "room_charges" : {
                     "enabled" : true
                  }
               }
            ],
            "status" : "UNOCCUPIED"
         },
         {
            "room_number" : "105",
            "services" : [
               {
                  "adult" : {
                     "enabled" : true
                  },
                  "room_charges" : {
                     "enabled" : false
                  }
               }
            ],
            "status" : "OCCUPIED"
```

And here is my code, that parses the JSON file, and outputs it into a table.

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents("response.json");

$data = json_decode($response, true);

?>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<div>
    <form id="response_form" action="#" method="POST" name="mainform"><br>
        <label for="text">&nbsp;Enter Room Number</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="response_search" id="text" rows="1" cols="47"> </textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>
<div id="response_data">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th width="188px">Room Number: </th>
                <th width="193px">Adult:</th>
                <th width="193px">Room Charges: </th>
                <th width="212px">Status: </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($data['data']['rooms'] as $info): ?>
                <tr id="scroll_through">
                    <td><?php echo $info['room_number']; ?></td>
                    <?php $services = reset($info['services']); ?>
                    <td><?php echo ($services['adult']['enabled'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>                
                    <td><?php echo ($services['room_charges']['enabled'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $info['status']; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

You'll notice in my code above that I have a `form` where I'd like to make this happen. The steps that I have taken are as follows:

1. I have tried changing the `action` of the `form`, to `<action='<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` and then writing an `if` statement that attempts to match the text from the form to `$info['room_number'];`but that didn't work at all... To be honest, I'm not even sure if I am doing it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send the form to the server.
Just make the id of each room row in the table unique (for example #room_104, #room_105) and handle the form submit with javascript (jQuery in the example):

```
$('#response_form').submit(function() {
    window.location.hash = 'room_'+$('#text').val();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this:

In your output add a class per row E.G

```
   class="room<?= $info['room_number']; ?>
```

then use jquery like this:

```
//button clicked
$("#searchBtn").click(function(event){

    roomNo = "room" + event.target.id;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + roomNo).offset().top - 200
    }, 800, function(){
        //This will flash the row
        $('#' + roomNo).fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0).fadeTo('slow', 0.5).fadeTo('slow', 1.0);
    });

});
```

I have not tested this but use something similar on a site